Finding lower bound of a function for squeeze theorem
I was instructed to find the functions in order to squeeze the following limit:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+1} - 2\sqrt{x+2} \right)
$$
I have found the upper bound to be
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{x+2} - 2\sqrt{x+2} \right)
$$
which is just $0$
but for the lower bound I had some problems, as it needs to be purely calculated by using determinate values (no $\infty-\infty$ or $0*\infty$) and known limits.

We have the following lower bound:
$$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+1} - 2\sqrt{x + 2} \ge 2(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x + 2})$$
The right-hand side of this inequality tends to $0$ as $x \to \infty$, because
$$
(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x + 2})(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x + 2}) = x - (x + 2) = -2
$$
so that
$$
(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x + 2}) = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x + 2}}
$$
and the fraction on the right-hand side of the above equation tends to $0$ as $x \to \infty$ because the numerator is constant and the denominator tends to $\infty$.

More generally and directly, $\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x+b}=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt{x+b}}$ tends (monotonically) to $0$ as $x\to\infty$. Apply this to $(a,b)=(0,2)$ and to $(a,b)=(1,2)$, and add.
You can of course "squeeze" it between itself and $0$, but with no gain. The "instruction to squeeze" you were given sounds unreasonable for monotonic functions, like yours.

Good point, but the OP's exercise required the use of the squeeze theorem.

I know @Rob, whence my last sentence.

I added a second "last sentence", to drive the point home.

I agree, the requirement to use the squeeze theorem is weird here.

@AnneBauval: I haven't been a student or an instructor for many years but I always found it odd for the instructor to provide a "mandatory hint", so I very much agree with your last paragraph. In this case, I just rather mindlessly supplied what the OP was asking for - the key algebraic point (IMHO) here being that, if you see a problem involving sums or differences of square roots then a good strategy is to try to use the difference of two squares equation to eliminate the square roots.
